# Why I am getting Selenium init error on constructor?

Tags: java, selenium, pageobjects

sorry, I don't know if I constructed the title properly. But the problem I have is that when I created page object `Tile` and instantiazed it on Test page it gives error just after opening the page.
code below:

```
public class Tile {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private String title;
    private WebElement titleEl;

    public Tile(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        this.titleEl = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='xpathGoesHere']"));
        this.title = titleEl.getText();
     }

    public WebElement getTitleEl() {
        return titleEl;
    }

    public void setTitleEl(WebElement titleEl) {
        this.titleEl = titleEl;
    }

   public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
```

and there's a separate page for Tiles (as a component)

```
public class Tiles {
    private WebDriver driver;

    public Tiles(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }
```

another page:

```
public class ThePage extends BasePage {

    private final Tile tile;
    private final Tiles tiles;

    public ThePage(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
        this.tile = new Tile(driver);
        this.tiles = new Tiles(driver);
    }

    public Tile tile() {
        return tile;
    }

    public Tilesresults() {
        return tiles;
    }

}
```

and on Test page:

```
public class SomeTest extends BaseTest {
    private static String URL = "https://www.page.com/home/";
private Tile tile;
private ThePage page;
private String link = "link";

@BeforeMethod
public void setup() {
    driver.get(URL);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    page = new ThePage(driver);
}

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    // code goes here
    tile = new Tile(driver);
    tiles.results().getTiles();
    tile.getTitle();
}
```

}

I tried many things and I just no longer have ideas, I also checked POM pages online but couldnt find why it doesnt work. Help please, I am new to this
P.S. the page goes like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8A0s.png)

Comment: As per image Tiles Page Class contains Tile Class so this is kind of HAS A relationship but I am not able to see Tile object reference in Tiles Page Class.

Comment: right, corrected. But this is not it. I get error (and was getting it before):

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: //div[@id='pathxyz']
//...
at Tile.<init>(Tile.java:21)
 at ThePage.<init>(ThePage.java:10)
 at Monsterest.setup(Test.java:24)

But the locator is good, I checked it in dev tools.

Comment: (it indicates at this line>>

this.titleEl = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='xpathGoesHere']"));

Is it possible that locator is wrong? I am pretty sure it is correct

Comment: I added exact solution.

Comment: @AmitJain maybe this is a problem with webelement itself. I noticed I have issues with initializing it the way as above, i.e. 
`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='xpathGoesHere']"))` < it always fails with <init> error. Only I can do it with: 
`getElement() { return driver.findElement(By.xpath("//xpath"))}`
Why is that? I dont understand it

Comment: can you tell where u initialized driver ? I cannot see it in the code... There is no `driver=new ChromeDriver();`c
Yes you are right using `findElement` in constructor is poor design...

Comment: @AmitJain it is in Test class in  `@BeforeMethod`
Why `findElement ` is a poor design? which is better? I cannot find anything about it online. All sources online suggest using those > findElement, that's why I can't find any solution

Comment: "I said using findElement inside constructor is poor design"

You have to put driver initialization in BaseTest and every test class will extend this class, other wise driver will initialize for every test u wrote ....

Comment: @AmitJain ok, but why using it inside constructor is bad idea? And what is the alternatice? I need to return Object of `Tile` together with its field: title, description etc

Answer (score 1):

Add explicit wait in constructor, because it might be possible that element is taking time to load. If this does not work then xpath needs to be updated.

```
WebElement element=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("ur xpath here")));
```

As per image Tiles Page Class contains Tile Class so this is kind of `HAS A` relationship So we need to add Tile Class object reference in Tiles Page Class

```
public class Tiles {
    private WebDriver driver;
    public Tile tile;
    public Tiles(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }
```